# CakePHP Sending Files

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to render images/pdfs that exist outside of my webroot. So this is what I'm doing in my controller to Send the File - as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files). But I'm getting a Fatal Error. Any ideas why and how to fix this? I'm running CakePHP 2.4.5.

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$path = '/path/to/valid/file.pdf';
$this->response->file($path);
return $this->response;
```

Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Folder::slashTerm()

Stack trace:

1. {main}() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/app/webroot/index.php:0
2. Dispatcher->dispatch() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/app/webroot/index.php:96
3. Dispatcher->_invoke() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php:160
4. Controller->invokeAction() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php:185
5. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php:490
6. PagesController->load_media() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php:490
7. CakeResponse->file() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/app/Controller/PagesController.php:227
8. File->__construct() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php:1265
9. File->pwd() /Path/To/My/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Utility/File.php:91

Comment: I do not have a Model named Folder. I'm using the PagesController here for testing and clarity on this post. It will ultimately live somewhere else. The controller used should have no impact on this Fatal Error - would it?

Comment: When I do get_class() - it returns "Folder" correctly. However, when I do get_included_files() it returns a big list which includes: /lib/Cake/Utility/File.php but I do not see /lib/Cake/Utility/Folder.php in there. Why would that be? My File.php has App::uses('Folder', 'Utility'); at the top. Weird.

Comment: What should be enough to solve the problem? When I do this: get_class_methods($this->Folder) it returns an empty array.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I have a Plugin/Vendor with a class Folder. I think I'm close to getting this resolved. Thanks guys, your input helped me find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I had a Plugin that had a class Folder that was taking this over.

Comment: Could you update your answer with what plugin was it? And if your solution was to just kill that plugin or another one? That way this answer can be helpful to someone else with the same problem. Also, once you do that, accept your own answer :)

Comment: I have a custom Plugin(from before my time) that uses a class Folder. I simply renamed the class to "MyFolder" and updated the code accordingly. It says I will be able to accept my own answer in 2 days.